# inequality about Inner product and norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products

If $m\times n~(m<n)$ matrix $A$ satisfy the following condition $(1-\delta)||s||_2^2\leqslant \|As\|^2_2\leqslant (1+\delta)\|s\|_2^2$ for all the $n \times 1$ vector with no more than $k$ nonzero entries, we call $A$ satisfy the $k$-th RIP condition.

Multiple $A$ by a $n \times n$ matrix at the right, we get $AB$, will $AB$ still satisfy the $k$-th RIP condition?
If not, anyone can give me a counterexample?
tks a lot.

Comment: Just taking $B=kI_n$ lets you get the middle term as big as you want while the other two remain unchanged...